# component rerenders multiple times and adds default users repeatedly

Tags: reactjs, redux

At this point I can't think straight about this problem anymore:

I have an App that lets one create 'bases.' When accessing a newly created base component, the component fetches a user list which is then rendered on the new component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUsersOfList());
}
```

A reducer in the background adds the users to the state (if any). Default is:

```
const initialState = {
    userBases: [],
}
```

When accessing the newly created component I want to add (POST request) a default user (which is the creator of the base) and display it. I want this done only once, and want to prevent the adding from happening one than once with a check:

```
render() {
    if (
        this.props.userBases.length !== 0 &&
        this.props.currentBase.id !== undefined
    ) {
        const userName = this.props.currentAuthUser;
        const baseId = this.props.currentBase.id;
        const acceptedMembership = true;
        const isCreator = true;
        this.props.dispatch(
            addUserToList(baseId, userName, acceptedMembership, isCreator)
        );
    }
```

I am somehow greatly messed up on the if statement, so that a request likes this fires dozens, if not hundreds of times. How hard can it be to assemble an if statement that returns a simple .map of the userBases if exist, or add and display exactly one default user with the same name as the creator of the base itself?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling fetchUsersOfList() in componentDidMount it will force a re-render. Try moving your logic to componentWillMount instead

edit: Each time you set the state in your reducer it will also force a re-render

Comment: This is a bad idea:
`Note:

These methods are considered legacy and you should avoid them in new code:

UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`